# Unsupervised feature selection using numpy.corrcoef

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to perform pairwise comparison to select the rows of `subset` with a correlation > 0.05.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# pairwise correlation
c = np.corrcoef(subset.T)
c = pd.DataFrame(c)
s = c.unstack()
so = s.sort_values(kind="quicksort", ascending=False)
so = np.abs(so)
#so = int(np.argmax(so))

# Retrieve only if value in 3rd column > 0.05
thresh2 = 0.05
so_sub = so.loc[so.iloc[:,-1:] > 0.05]
subset = subset.iloc[so_sub]
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 23>()
     21 # Retrieve only if value in 3rd column > 0.05
     22 thresh2 = 0.05
---> 23 so_sub = so.loc[so.iloc[:,-1:] > 0.05]
     24 mrna_subset = mrna_subset.iloc[so_sub]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1097, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   1095     if self._is_scalar_access(key):
   1096         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
-> 1097     return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1098 else:
   1099     # we by definition only have the 0th axis
   1100     axis = self.axis or 0

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1594, in _iLocIndexer._getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1593 def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: tuple):
-> 1594     tup = self._validate_tuple_indexer(tup)
   1595     with suppress(IndexingError):
   1596         return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:900, in _LocationIndexer._validate_tuple_indexer(self, key)
    895 @final
    896 def _validate_tuple_indexer(self, key: tuple) -> tuple:
    897     """
    898     Check the key for valid keys across my indexer.
    899     """
--> 900     key = self._validate_key_length(key)
    901     key = self._expand_ellipsis(key)
    902     for i, k in enumerate(key):

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:939, in _LocationIndexer._validate_key_length(self, key)
    937             raise IndexingError(_one_ellipsis_message)
    938         return self._validate_key_length(key)
--> 939     raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    940 return key

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Input:

`subset.iloc[0:4,0:4]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'A2M': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01': 40686.22,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': 11009.03,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': 3180.79,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01': 16771.52},
 'A4GALT': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01': 2583.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': 4720.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': 2768.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01': 1689.0},
 'AAK1': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01': 2590.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': 2562.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': 2715.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01': 3010.0},
 'AAMP': {'TCGA.2K.A9WE.01': 4478.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01': 4518.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01': 5936.0,
  'TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01': 4139.0}})
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact expected output is unclear, but I would use [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) directly, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to reshape as 1D and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) to filter the values:

```
out = (subset.corr()
 .stack().abs()
 .loc[lambda s: (s>0.5)
      & (s.index.get_level_values(0)   # also filtering out the self
      != s.index.get_level_values(1))  # correlations (optional)
     ]
)
```

Output:

```
A2M     AAMP      0.552469
A4GALT  AAK1      0.760262
AAK1    A4GALT    0.760262
AAMP    A2M       0.552469
dtype: float64
```

To fix your code, you would need to use `so_sub = so[so>0.5]` as you already have a Series (there are no columns).

Comment: My expected output is to keep only the features in `subset` that correspond to the `out`

Comment: @melolili please provide the explicit expected output that matches your minimal input, also what is `mrna_subset`?